# Simplest way to pass real-time data from sql database in nodejs to html every 1 second

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js, ajax

I am working on an app and i need to pass real time data from my sql database (i am using node-mysql module) to html file that i am rendering . I can pass static data easily but i need to pass dynamic data.
**1 entry should be fetched from the database and passed to the html file.**

It will be very helpful if you'r answer is as basic as possible because I am a beginner at it.

Comment: This is a job for web sockets; look up websocket tutorials specific to the nodejs framework you are using.

Comment: Websocket "API" is slightly more tricky to implent if compared to basic HTTP. In case you run in troubles by implementing functionality with WS, I'd rather start by doing Fetch in one second intervals. For Websockets I'd start to have look at https://markshust.com/2013/11/07/creating-nodejs-server-client-socket-io-mysql/

I did this same some time ago for PostgreSQL by following http://darrenoneill.co.uk/post/real-time-web-apps-postgresql-and-node/ tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. There are two ways :

1. using AJAX calls at client side and http-msgs module to interact with the AJAX requests .
2. Using socket.io . Using it is easy and fun but it is not old enough and not used very often in industry projects .

I went with the first one :)